# Why are my posts inside the loop taking up the full width of the screen?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

On my list of posts page, I would like to display 3 posts on each row. (Desktop view only)

With the following code, each post is taking up the entire width of the screen with each post starting on a new line. How can I work around this?

Here is the code in my index.php which initially targets the loop.

```
<section id="portfolio" class="wow fadeIn hide" data-wow-duration="2s">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                    
      <?php
      endif;
                        
         /* Start the Loop */
         while ( have_posts() ) :

           the_post();

           get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', "grid" );

        endwhile;
        else :

      endif;
      ?>

  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

And here is the code in my content-grid.php which displays the content of the loop.

```
 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <!-- Start of featured project column --->
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="img-container thumbnail">
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <div class="hover-block">
              <h3 class="project-name"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
    </div> <!-- End of featured project column --->

 </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Comment: your `<article>` element, is probably not grid based. Maybe put that inside your column  class., both start and end

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks a lot!